# Trigger to update the case owner based on the values on a pick list

Tags: apex, trigger

I’m a newbie to Salesforce and need some help building a trigger.
I need a trigger to update the Owner of a case based on the values selected within a pick list and populate the Owner field with the createdby field data.

Field name = Status

Pick list values =

**Priced – (Initial)**

**Priced – (Re-Priced)**

**Price File Loaded**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: And how do those picklist values correspond to Owner?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you didnt really explain how the picklist values correspond with the owner, but in order to change the OwnerId to the CreatedById is fairly simple.  You can just change the owner assignment in the if statements based on the logic you need

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case(before update) {
   for(Case c : Trigger.new()){
       if(c.Status == 'Priced – (Initial)' || c.Status == 'Priced – (Re-Priced)' || c.Status == 'Price File Loaded'{
           c.OwnerId = c.CreatedById;
       }    
   }
}
```

Comment: When any of those values get selected the case gets reassigned back to the person who created the case.  So the case would get assigned to a pricing analyst and when they are done they change the status to one of the three from the pick list and it gets assigned back to the person who created the case.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like this is an update trigger, not an insert.  I have adjusted the code, hope that helps

Comment: Actually the other code worked good for me.  Thanks